# Restrict Client Apps IN Azure AAD

Tags: azure

I have an AAD Tenant.
I registered one Service App inside the Tenant.

I registered another Client App 1 inside the Tenant & Retrieved Client ID & Secret.

My friend registered another Client App 2 inside the Tenant & Retrieved Client ID & Secret.

NOW both the Client App are able to Access the Service!

BUT i wanted to restrict that only Client App 1 should be able to access the service.

Please advice how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict access based on Application roles (**not on behalf of user**)

1. Add an appRole to the "Service App" manifest.

[image]

2. Go to "ClientApp1" API permissions and add the "Service App" application permission created in Step1. **Make sure the admin consent is granted.**

[image]

3. Get the access token to "Service App" using ClientID and ClientSecret it should have the new role; in your "Service App" controller code add **Authorize**(Roles = "ServiceConsumer") attribute

   `[Authorize(Roles = "ServiceConsumer")]
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
   [ApiController]
   public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
   { }`

Comment: Yup, this is the correct way. Define and require app permissions. Of course any admin can still assign those permissions to another app, but well, they are an admin.

Comment: Thanks Jeshwel!  But we tried this already - we are seeking a No-Code change approach though - Can we do this in AAD Configuration level?

Comment: I can try for some alternatives, but they may not be the MS ideal way of doing things :) . But first let me understand, by "No-Code" change approach, you mean not getting an access token for "Service App" or your problem is hard-coding the role in controller?
2. In your context is there any chance for the same user to access "ClientApp1" & "ClientApp2" (If not, we can think of some solution in that direction)?